# ImportError: Module use of python39.dll conflicts with this version of Python

Tags: tensorflow

I've been trying to import Tensorflow to jupypter notebook in a Python3 virtual env and I'm getting and error. I also have Python 2 installed.

In the virtual enviroment I've already installed this packages to make it work in Jupyter notebook:
tensorflow
numpy (upgrade)
ipy_kernel
nb_conda

From Jupyter Notebook i can select the virtual enviroment with the correct packages installed and can import packages like numpy but when trying to import tensorflow I get this error:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
~\.conda\envs\py3-TF2.0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>
     63   try:
---> 64     from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
     65   # This try catch logic is because there is no bazel equivalent for py_extension.

ImportError: Module use of python39.dll conflicts with this version of Python.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-fc0b9e4a13ce> in <module>
----> 1 from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *

~\.conda\envs\py3-TF2.0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py in <module>
     39 import sys as _sys
     40 
---> 41 from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
     42 from tensorflow.python.util.lazy_loader import LazyLoader as _LazyLoader
     43 

~\.conda\envs\py3-TF2.0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py in <module>
     38 # pylint: disable=wildcard-import,g-bad-import-order,g-import-not-at-top
     39 
---> 40 from tensorflow.python.eager import context
     41 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow as _pywrap_tensorflow
     42 

~\.conda\envs\py3-TF2.0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\context.py in <module>
     33 from tensorflow.core.protobuf import config_pb2
     34 from tensorflow.core.protobuf import rewriter_config_pb2
---> 35 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tfe
     36 from tensorflow.python import tf2
     37 from tensorflow.python.client import pywrap_tf_session

~\.conda\envs\py3-TF2.0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tfe.py in <module>
     26 
     27 # pylint: disable=invalid-import-order,g-bad-import-order, wildcard-import, unused-import
---> 28 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
     29 from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tfe import *

~\.conda\envs\py3-TF2.0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py in <module>
     81 for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
     82 above this error message when asking for help.""" % traceback.format_exc()
---> 83   raise ImportError(msg)
     84 
     85 # pylint: enable=wildcard-import,g-import-not-at-top,unused-import,line-too-long

ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Tom\.conda\envs\py3-TF2.0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 64, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python._pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
ImportError: Module use of python39.dll conflicts with this version of Python.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tensorflow nightly version support Python 3.9 for all the operating system.

```
pip install tf-nightly
```

Please check [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/44485#issuecomment-797037619) thread.